# function variables dont change from initial value , no idea why

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

in the following function maxnum and minnum always stay at their infinity value and don't get the value they should in the while loop, so when i log it to the console it says infinity and -infinity respectively, any ideas?

```js
// Read 10 numbers and print
// :a.The maximum number.b.The minimum number.c.The average
printMaxMinSum();

function printMaxMinSum() {
  var numsCount = 10
  var count = 0;
  var sum = 0
  // var inputNumber = +prompt('Enter your number')
  var minNum = Infinity
  var maxNum = -Infinity


  while (count < numsCount) {
    debugger
    var inputNumber = +prompt('Enter your number')
    if (minNum < inputNumber) minNum = inputNumber
    if (maxNum > inputNumber) maxNum = inputNumber
    sum += inputNumber
    count++
  }

  var avg = sum / numsCount
  console.log('The higest number is: ', maxNum, 'the lowest number is: ', minNum, 'the average is: ', avg)
  console.log('avg is', avg)
}
```

Comment: You've got the comparisons wrong, they should be the other way around. `minNum > inputNumber` and `maxNum < inputNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at these lines:

```
if (minNum < inputNumber) minNum = inputNumber
if (maxNum > inputNumber) maxNum = inputNumber
```

Think about the logic: `minNum < inputNumber` will always be `false` because `minNum` is `Infinity` (which is always larger than any number).

The same for the second line because `maxNum` is `-Infinity` which is always less than any number.

Reverse the logic:

```
if (inputNumber < minNum) minNum = inputNumber
if (inputNumber > maxNum) maxNum = inputNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the first input number as a minNum and maxNum

```html
// Read 10 numbers and print
    // :a.The maximum number.b.The minimum number.c.The average
    printMaxMinSum();
    function printMaxMinSum() {
        var numsCount = 10
        var count = 0;
        var sum = 0
         var inputNumber = +prompt('Enter your number')
         sum += inputNumber
        var minNum = inputNumber
        var maxNum = inputNumber


        while (count < numsCount-1) {
          console.log(numsCount)
            var inputNumber = +prompt('Enter your number')
            if (minNum < inputNumber) minNum = inputNumber
            if (maxNum > inputNumber) maxNum = inputNumber
            sum += inputNumber
            count=count+1;
            console.log(count)
        }

        var avg = sum / numsCount
        console.log('The higest number is: ', maxNum, 'the lowest number is: ', minNum, 'the average is: ', avg)
        console.log('avg is', avg)
    }
```